# Redirecting via .htaccess to .php with arguments in current folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect something like `foo/bar` to `?foo=bar`, so I can do `www.mydomain.com/hey/foo/bar` to `www.mydomain.com/hey/?foo=bar`, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ ?foo=bar [NC]
```

But this doesn't work. How would I accomplish this? I tried adding a forward slash behind the question mark, but that makes it link to the root directory.

Thanks,
Jengerer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that the problem wasn't in the redirection, but in the links that were made after the redirection.

After redirecting from `/foo/bar` to `/?foo=bar`, the CSS links and images were poorly matched because it was now looking for local links within the `/foo/bar` directory, which doesn't exist. What an interesting 'glitch'.

Comment: Try using absolute paths for stuff like your CSS: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/style.css" />`

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing, as it seems to be the only possible solution to the problem (sorry for removing my comment, I decided to put it in a separate answer for anyone else who runs into the problem).

Comment: You can set base href in the document header. Then you can use relative urls for assets and you only need to update the base href if your .htaccess rewrite rules change. The Indium framework, which is going to be released Real Soon Now, does automatic .htaccess aware base href settings for you in the bootstrap code generation process. It can do that because it also controls .htaccess generation in order to support slugs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the actual file you're rewriting to. Using `?foo=bar` isn't pointing at any file in particular.

Use the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?$1=$2 [NC]
```

Notice that I'm pointing to the file `index.php`. `$1` is replaced by whatever is matched by the first `(.*)` and `$2` by the second. So, if someone browsed to `foo/bar`, they would be taken to `index.php?foo=bar`.

**Important Note:** If you choose to use `(.*)` and accept any character for the variable name or value and plan to use this information in database queries, you'll want to be certain to escape this content properly using your database's escape functions (`mysql_real_escape_string` or `pg_escape_string`) or by using prepared statements.

If you're having problems with style or elements on the page not showing correct because you're using relative paths, you'll need to use absolute paths starting at the root. Otherwise, your pages style, images, etc. would break.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try removing the ^ from `^foo/(.*)$`?

Comment: It's definitely not the expression it's trying to match that's the problem, because it redirects it fine, but just not to the right address. I'd enable rewrite logging so I could see what it's filling in, but I get a "500 Internal Server Error" every time I do, likely 'cause I don't have write permissions for the log-file...

Answer (score 0):

When you place the .htaccess in your root it should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$ $1?$2=$3 [L]
```

when you place the .htaccess in your "hey" folder, it should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$ ?$1=$2 [L]
```